# How can I handle return values from event delegates in C#?

Tags: c#, events, delegates, return-value

So I was curious myself, as the more I develop the more use I have for getting data back from events, so I did a -little- looking around and noted that there wasn't much in the way of information on handling responses from event delegates.

It's one thing to have a delegate with a return value, and execute a method of said delegation, and get its return value, but what do you do when you have an event fire off multitudes of delegates? How do you determine what happened in each of those delegates?

Comment: Q&A'd this for the sake of sharing some code that I'm already finding useful - hope it's helpful to someone else, and I'm happy to hear feedback on my answer - or to expand on it for that matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Q&A Style -

Because there was so little available on the topic, and because it was all so diverse, I opted to put something up with a little style - something that I believe is a rather thorough 'event response handler'.

In the following code sample ( which I have just updated with my latest rendition ( more to come, more than likely)) you'll find code that supports firing of an event, and eventual returning of data from any methods subsequently executed. The 'Event' class that is used to pass down data to event delegates, will eventually contain a set of EventResults that can be evaluated at a later time. This grants a developer the ability to respond to failed delegates after firing an event.

The first class is an 'Event', and contains a few variables that can offer some valuable feedback to your delegates - things like what object the event is coming from, a simple string message, the associated stack, etc.

The event class Also contains a collection of 'EventResponses'; which brings us to our second class... An EventResponse. This class has two 'types'; which can offer immediate feedback for sub-execution.

How this is achieved is through requirement of the 'SourceEvent' in the EventResponse constructors; And through execution of the 'EventResponse.FinalizeResponse' method - which adds the event response to the associated event. I have just finished modifying the EventResponse to be Disposable, and inside of the Disposal, I examine the EventResponse's SourceEvent, and if the SourceEvent does not contain an entry for the EventResponse I am disposing - I create a new copy of the EventResponse, and run FinalizeResponse on the new copy.

The ultimate value of all of this is wide-spread - if you'll note an event In the Event class, called 'OnResponseFailure', and similarly the 'AddResponse' method on the event, you'll note that when an event encounters a response that is considered a 'failure'; it throws an event itself to potentially notify the initial calling method.

The Event class also contains a couple of fields that could be used to analyze failure or success inside of responses After execution of all of the delegates; which I'll leave for you to meander through.

Similarly, the EventResponse class contains a few fields that can be used to return even more data back up to the method that initiated the event, should it be necessary - things like the Response's Source Object, and a message.

I hope this is a helpful Q&A - as I feel that it is going to help ME Greatly in creating robust, responsive code. Happy hunting.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Reflection;

namespace MyNamespace.Events
{
    public class EventDriver : IDisposable
    {
        #region Supporting Events
        public List<EventResponse> FireEvent(String EventName, Event Event)
        {
            List<EventResponse> ResponseList = new List<EventResponse>();

            Type LocalType = this.GetType();

            Type TargetType = null;

            if ((TargetType = this.FindEventType(LocalType, EventName)) == null)
            {
                return ResponseList;
            }
            else
            {
                FieldInfo TargetField = TargetType.GetField(EventName, BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public);

                MulticastDelegate EventDelegates = (MulticastDelegate) TargetField.GetValue(this);

                if (EventDelegates == null)
                {
                    return ResponseList;
                }
                else
                {
                    foreach (Delegate TargetDelegate in EventDelegates.GetInvocationList())
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            Object DelegateResponse = TargetDelegate.DynamicInvoke(new Object[] { Event });
                            EventResponse Response = (EventResponse)DelegateResponse;
                            ResponseList.Add(Response);
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                        }
                    }

                    return ResponseList;
                }
            }
        }

        private Type FindEventType(Type RootType, String EventName)
        {
            if (RootType == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            else if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(EventName))
            {
                return null;
            }
            else
            {
                FieldInfo EventField = null;

                foreach (FieldInfo Method in RootType.GetFields(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public))
                    if (Method.Name == EventName)
                    {
                        EventField = Method;
                        break;
                    }

                if (EventField == null)
                {
                    if (RootType.BaseType == null)
                        return null;
                    else
                        return this.FindEventType(RootType.BaseType, EventName);
                }
                else
                {
                    return RootType;
                }
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region Dispoability
        public virtual void Dispose()
        {
            this.FireEvent("OnDispose", new Event(this, "Object is being disposed."));
        }
        #endregion
    }
}


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Reflection;

namespace MyNamespace.Events
{
    #region Delegates
    public delegate EventResponse EventHandler(Event Event);
    #endregion

    #region Enumerations
    public enum EventResponseType
    {
        Success, Failure
    }
    #endregion

    public class Event
    {
        #region Events
        public event EventHandler OnResponseFailure = null;
        #endregion

        #region Fields
        public Object EventSource = null;

        public DateTime EventTime = DateTime.Now;

        public String EventMessage = String.Empty;

        protected StackTrace _EventStackTrace = null;

        public StackTrace EventStackTrace
        {
            get
            {
                return this._EventStackTrace;
            }
        }

        protected List<EventResponse> _EventResponses = null;

        public List<EventResponse> EventResponses
        {
            get
            {
                List<EventResponse> EventResponses = new List<EventResponse>();

                lock (this._EventResponses)
                {
                    foreach (EventResponse Response in this._EventResponses)
                        EventResponses.Add(Response);
                }

                return EventResponses;
            }
        }

        public Boolean HasFailedResponses
        {
            get
            {
                if (this.FailedResponses.Count > 0)
                    return true;
                return false;
            }
        }

        public Boolean HasSuccessfulResponses
        {
            get
            {
                if (this.SucceessfulResponses.Count > 0)
                    return true;
                return false;
            }
        }

        public List<EventResponse> FailedResponses
        {
            get
            {
                List<EventResponse> FailedResponses = new List<EventResponse>();

                foreach (EventResponse Response in this.EventResponses)
                    if (Response.ResponseType == EventResponseType.Failure)
                        FailedResponses.Add(Response);
                return FailedResponses;
            }
        }

        public List<EventResponse> SucceessfulResponses
        {
            get
            {
                List<EventResponse> SucceededResponses = new List<EventResponse>();

                foreach (EventResponse Response in this.EventResponses)
                    if (Response.ResponseType == EventResponseType.Success)
                        SucceededResponses.Add(Response);
                return SucceededResponses;
            }
        }

        protected List<Event> _ForwardedEvents = null;

        public List<Event> ForwardedEvents
        {
            get
            {
                List<Event> FowardedEvents = new List<Event>();

                lock (this._ForwardedEvents)
                    foreach (Event ForwardedEvent in this.ForwardedEvents)
                        ForwardedEvents.Add(ForwardedEvent);

                return ForwardedEvents;
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region Constructors
        protected Event()
        {
            this._EventResponses = new List<EventResponse>();
            this._EventStackTrace = new StackTrace();
            this._ForwardedEvents = new List<Event>();
        }

        public Event(Object EventSource, String EventMessage, DateTime EventTime)
            : this()
        {
            this.EventSource = EventSource;
            this.EventTime = EventTime;
            this.EventMessage = EventMessage;

            return;
        }

        public Event(Object EventSource, String EventMessage)
            : this(EventSource, EventMessage, DateTime.Now)
        {
        }
        #endregion

        #region Supporting Methods
        public void AddResponse(EventResponse Response)
        {
            lock (this._EventResponses)
            {
                this._EventResponses.Add(Response);
            }

            if (Response.ResponseType == EventResponseType.Failure)
                this.TriggerResponseFailure(Response);

            return;
        }

        public EventResponse CreateResponse()
        {
            return new EventResponse(this);
        }

        public EventResponse CreateResponse(Object ResponseSource, Object ResponseObject, DateTime ResponseTime, String ResponseMessage, EventResponseType ResponseType)
        {
            return new EventResponse(this, ResponseSource, ResponseObject, ResponseTime, ResponseMessage, ResponseType);
        }

        public EventResponse CreateResponse(Object ResponseSource, Object ResponseObject, DateTime ResponseTime, EventResponseType ResponseType)
        {
            return this.CreateResponse(ResponseSource, ResponseObject, ResponseTime, String.Empty, ResponseType);
        }

        public EventResponse CreateResponse(Object ResponseSource, Object ResponseObject, DateTime ResponseTime)
        {
            return this.CreateResponse(ResponseSource, ResponseObject, ResponseTime, EventResponseType.Success);
        }

        public EventResponse CreateResponse(Object ResponseSource, Object ResponseObject, EventResponseType ResponseType)
        {
            return this.CreateResponse(ResponseSource, ResponseObject, DateTime.Now, ResponseType);
        }

        public EventResponse CreateResponse(Object ResponseSource, Object ResponseObject)
        {
            return this.CreateResponse(ResponseSource, ResponseObject, EventResponseType.Success);
        }

        public EventResponse CreateResponse(Object ResponseSource, String ResponseMessage)
        {
            return this.CreateResponse(ResponseSource, null, DateTime.Now, ResponseMessage, EventResponseType.Success);
        }

        public EventResponse CreateResponse(String ResponseMessage)
        {
            return this.CreateResponse(null, ResponseMessage);
        }

        public EventResponse CreateResponse(Object ResponseSource)
        {
            return this.CreateResponse(ResponseSource, String.Empty);
        }

        public Event Forward(Object ForwardFrom)
        {
            Event ForwardedEvent = new Event(ForwardFrom, this.EventMessage, this.EventTime);

            lock (this._ForwardedEvents)
                this._ForwardedEvents.Add(ForwardedEvent);

            return ForwardedEvent;
        }
        #endregion

        #region Event Triggers
        protected void TriggerResponseFailure(EventResponse Response)
        {
            if (this.OnResponseFailure != null)
                this.OnResponseFailure(new Event(Response, "A failure was encountered while executing this event."));
            return;
        }
        #endregion
    }

    public class EventResponse : IDisposable
    {
        #region Fields
        protected Event _SourceEvent = null;

        public Event SourceEvent
        {
            get
            {
                return this._SourceEvent;
            }
        }

        public Object ResponseSource = null;

        public Type ResponseSourceType
        {
            get
            {
                return this.ResponseSource.GetType();
            }
        }

        public Object ResponseObject = null;

        public Type ResponseObjectType
        {
            get
            {
                return this.ResponseObject.GetType();
            }
        }

        public DateTime ResponseTime = DateTime.Now;

        public String ResponseMessage = String.Empty;

        protected StackTrace _ResponseStackTrace = null;

        public StackTrace ResponseStackTrace
        {
            get
            {
                return this._ResponseStackTrace;
            }
        }

        public EventResponseType ResponseType = EventResponseType.Success;
        #endregion

        #region Constructors
        public EventResponse(Event SourceEvent)
        {
            this._SourceEvent = SourceEvent;

            this._ResponseStackTrace = new StackTrace();
        }

        public EventResponse(Event SourceEvent, Object ResponseSource, Object ResponseObject, DateTime ResponseTime, String ResponseMessage, EventResponseType ResponseType)
            : this(SourceEvent)
        {
            this.ResponseSource = ResponseSource;
            this.ResponseObject = ResponseObject;
            this.ResponseTime = ResponseTime;
            this.ResponseMessage = ResponseMessage;
            this.ResponseType = ResponseType;

            return;
        }

        public EventResponse(Event SourceEvent, Object ResponseSource, Object ResponseObject, DateTime ResponseTime, EventResponseType ResponseType)
            : this(SourceEvent,ResponseSource,ResponseObject,ResponseTime,String.Empty,ResponseType)
        {
        }

        public EventResponse(Event SourceEvent, Object ResponseSource, Object ResponseObject, DateTime ResponseTime)
            : this(SourceEvent, ResponseSource, ResponseObject, ResponseTime, EventResponseType.Success)
        {
        }

        public EventResponse(Event SourceEvent, Object ResponseSource, Object ResponseObject, EventResponseType ResponseType)
            : this(SourceEvent, ResponseSource, ResponseObject, DateTime.Now, ResponseType)
        {
        }

        public EventResponse(Event SourceEvent, Object ResponseSource, Object ResponseObject)
            : this(SourceEvent, ResponseSource, ResponseObject, EventResponseType.Success)
        {
        }

        public EventResponse(Event SourceEvent, Object ResponseSource, EventResponseType ResponseType)
            : this(SourceEvent, ResponseSource, null, DateTime.Now, String.Empty, ResponseType)
        {

        }

        public EventResponse(Event SourceEvent, Object ResponseSource, String ResponseMessage)
            : this(SourceEvent, ResponseSource, null, DateTime.Now, ResponseMessage, EventResponseType.Success)
        {

        }

        public EventResponse(Event SourceEvent, String ResponseMessage)
            : this( SourceEvent, null, ResponseMessage )
        {
        }
        #endregion

        #region Supporting Methods
        public void FinalizeResponse()
        {
            this.SourceEvent.AddResponse(this);
            return;
        }
        #endregion

        #region Overrides
        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (this.SourceEvent == null)
                return;
            else if (this.SourceEvent.EventResponses.Contains(this))
                return;
            else
            {
                EventResponse NewResponse = new EventResponse(this.SourceEvent, this.ResponseSource, this.ResponseObject, this.ResponseTime, this.ResponseMessage, this.ResponseType);
                NewResponse.FinalizeResponse();
                return;
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

More than likely I'll make more changes to all of this, add more constructors, and method overrides - but this is the version of the code I am currently using and it is performing marvelously for me.

The suggestion here is to extend your 'base' class with the 'EventDriver' class - this will give you the ability to use the 'EventDriver.FireEvent' method - which will return all EventResponses generated by a particular event.

All of this is fairly 'beta' and like I said I'll still be making changes, but this will be updated accordingly as I make further steps. Enjoy :)

Comment: Added graceful FinalizeResponse method handling... removed comments regarding.

Answer (score 1):

```
public delegate object GetObject();
public event GetObject MyEvent;

public IList<object> RaiseMyEvent()
{
    var myList = new List<object>();
    if (MyEvent != null)
        foreach (var handler in MyEvent.GetInvocationList())
            myList.Add(handler.DynamicInvoke());
    return myList;
}
```

Comment: @Servy why is that? I don't see anything obviously wrong with it.

Comment: Have you ever used an event like that?  Events are generally designed to push information, rather than to pull it.

Comment: This might be useful in an 'EventDriver' class; in that it could be used to facilitate automation of the FinalizeResponse method I reference in my own answer. Potentially a more graceful solution than forcing my delegates to execute this method on their own.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, code which is going to raise an event whose subscribers should return information will pass its subscribers an event object which either has a field where subscribers can place the information, or an object to which subscribers can feed it.  The former usage is preferred for situations where only the first subscriber who has anything to say will be of interest.  The latter usage is preferred in cases where many subscribers might all have something to add.

Comment: Valued input - and quite appreciated... I'd be interested in your review of the answer portion of my 'Q&A' which this was meant to be. I proposed a rather in-depth solution that is already paying dividends in my code minutes later.

Comment: @DigitalJedi805: I've not examined it in depth, but it seems overcomplicated for most scenarios I've seen; I don't see anything that suggests what you're trying to do that requires such complexity.

Comment: I haven't suggested any potential uses for it, but I can provide examples if you would like... I'm not sure that, you not understanding how this could all be used, is reason for nobody to want to use it. I have already found a few uses of this code in an application I'm actively developing. I'm not trying to knock your comments - it's a little bit of a complex tree of execution, and one that doesn't have use unless you are using a lot of events, but it'll help someone I'm sure; as it's already helped me.

Comment: @DigitalJedi805: Before people can benefit from something, they have to read it, and people are more likely to read something if they can see how it will benefit them.  The value of lengthy posts can thus be greatly enhanced if someone can tell within the first couple paragraphs what benefit they'll get from reading the remainder.

Comment: Opted to alter my opening statements in my response - and incorporate use of this answers content in a fairly full-featured response. Hope it's up to your standards. Thanks for the suggestion. I wouldn't mind some points for my giant Q&A :P